# Is it possible to use python multiprocessing with MS SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

We are using MS SQL Server for our solution with external python script to query a statistical database every morning, that returns a JSON-Stat. We then run that JSON-Stat through Pyjstat library function from_json_stat() to convert it from a JSON-Stat to pandas DataFrame which MS SQL Server can read.

On the largest tables from this national statistical database, this can take upto 7-10 mins, we had the idea of using python's multiprocessing to at least speed up from_json_stat. Running the code works flawlessly in python, however, when we then run the code through Microsoft's SQL Management Studio we get a pickle error on that very function we tried to speed up.

This is the relevant code, this works in python and we get major speed up on the biggest queries, but not through SSMS' python external script.

```py
def run_pyjstat(result_list):
    return pyjstat.from_json_stat(result_list.json(object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict), naming="id")[0]

def post_query():    
    meta_data = meta_filter()
    result_list = []

    for variables in meta_data:
        query = build_query(variables)
        data = requests.post(ssb_table.metadata_url, json=query)
        result_list.append(data)
        time.sleep(5.0)
    return result_list

def master():
    dataframes = []
    x = post_query()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    dataframes = pool.map(run_pyjstat, x)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    big_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
    return big_df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ssb_table = SSBTable(TableNumber)
    klass = RegionKLASS(["131", "104", "214", "231"])
    r = master()
```

This is the error we get and the one we have been getting

```
Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "D:\SQL-MSSQLSERVER-ExtensibilityData-PY\MSSQLSERVER01\0ECB2A7F-0698-4FA7-86E6-76EF41292E20\sqlindb.py", line 691, in transform
    r = master()
  File "D:\SQL-MSSQLSERVER-ExtensibilityData-PY\MSSQLSERVER01\0ECB2A7F-0698-4FA7-86E6-76EF41292E20\sqlindb.py", line 667, in master
    dataframes = pool.map(run_pyjstat, x)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 385, in _handle_tasks

Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
An external script error occurred: 
    put(task)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'transform.<locals>.run_pyjstat'

SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
```

Both of us that are hired for this project are juniors and primarily used Java in school. There are no other devs we can ask on the premise and searches on google doesn't yield many results on this particular issue. Maybe my google search skills are just bad.

We have considered moving away from MS SQL Server external_script and using Java, but at the moment it works without multiprocessing, albeit slower than we want to.

Is there any way to make this work with python external script?